# Can't Sign PDF using USB token epass2003 with C# iTextsharp 5.4.0 code . But when using Java itextsharp 5.5.8 i am able to sign the PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-certificate, dongle

Hi I am not able to sign the PDF using C# itextsharp 5.4.0 library

Following are the logs generated in Java Code which works fine:

```
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Checking certificate: CN=N C JAIN, SERIALNUMBER=2d9883a6f13cd6fb4416035766825e4b5ec823a871f883d3f3ee8eeb6e433c8d, ST=Delhi, OID.2.5.4.17=110020, OU="NEWGEN SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES LIMITED,ECID - 5810785", OID.2.5.4.20=f9cd01a6fbef84f253bf3830cab5caef7fc536e303639ff7e5c195f7488b032b, O=NEWGEN SOFTWARE TECHNOLOGIES LIMITED, C=IN
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Added CRL url: _https://www.ncodesolutions.com/repository/ncodeca14.crl
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Checking certificate: CN=(n)Code Solutions CA 2014, OID.2.5.4.51="301, GNFC Infotower", STREET="Bodakdev, S G Road, Ahmedabad", ST=Gujarat, OID.2.5.4.17=380054, OU=Certifying Authority, O=Gujarat Narmada Valley Fertilizers and Chemicals Limited, C=IN
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Added CRL url: _http://cca.gov.in/rw/resources/CCAIndia2014Latest.crl
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Checking certificate: CN=CCA India 2014, O=India PKI, C=IN
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Skipped CRL url (malformed): null
c.i.t.p.s.MakeSignature INFO  Processing com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.CrlClientOnline
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Checking CRL: _https://www.ncodesolutions.com/repository/ncodeca14.crl
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Skipped CRL: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target for _https://www.ncodesolutions.com/repository/ncodeca14.crl
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Checking CRL: _http://cca.gov.in/rw/resources/CCAIndia2014Latest.crl
c.i.t.p.s.CrlClientOnline INFO  Added CRL found at: _http://cca.gov.in/rw/resources/CCAIndia2014Latest.crl
```

NOTE: The java code works fine.

But the C# itextSharp code doesn't work . It is hitting the wrong URL which doesn't exist.

```
UrlList:
"_https://www.ncodesolutions.com/repository/ncodeca14.crl"
"_http://cca.gov.in/rw/resources/CCAIndia2014Latest.crl"
```

Retrieves the OCSP URL from the given certificate as.

**"https://www.ncodesolutions.com/repository/ncodeca.cer"**

**Which is different from the url's present in the above urlist and from java.**

```
Exception:The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Please Provide Help or solution for the same.

NOTE: _ is added before every link so that i could post my question.

Thanks

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the http headers from java and c#.  Make c# look like java results.  Usually you have to add additional headers to c# to get code to work.Could be a bad cookie.  Try java again and see if it still works.You may need to delete cookie from IE history manually to get to work.Every time you try new version of code remove cookie.Cookies have expiration date and bad cookies will stay until date expires.  A bad cookie will prevent you from getting good results.  Also check if code is using http 1.0 or 1.1.  1.1 doesn't work in Net an must set to 1.0.

Comment: Does it work with the C# version 5.5.12?

Comment: An identical question is currently being worked on by iText support. Are you the same customer?

Comment: If you are not, you should give more information. E.g. your certificate as seen via .Net.